# Unable to create an adapter with custom cards

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I'm using the [cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/CARDRECYCLERVIEW.md#intro) library for having cards in my Android app. It has pre-defined card layouts or we have an option to customize the layout.

While creating the adapter for recycler view, only the list of card objects with pre-defined card layouts are accepted. I get an error when I try to pass a list of custom cards to the constructor.

```
CardArrayRecyclerViewAdapter cardArrayRecyclerViewAdapter = new CardArrayRecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), customCards);
```

The above code shows an error. `customCards` is the list of custom card objects. How do I make it work ?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error:(53, 127) error: incompatible types: List<CustomCard> cannot be converted to List<Card>

Answer (score 0):

In your `CardArrayRecyclerViewAdapter` change `List<Card>` to `List<CustomCard>` in the constructor

Comment: The problem is `CardArrayRecyclerViewAdapter` is an in-built adapter in the library. Am I allowed to tweak it?

Comment: Then you have to pass `List<Card>` into the adapter. Post more of your code so that someone can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can write Custom card  adapter bellow

1. card adapter call just like

   ```
   List<CustomCard> cardlist = new ArrayList<>();
   recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   // recyclerView
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
   // create an Object for Adapter
   CardDataAdapter  mAdapter = new CardDataAdapter(cardlist);
   // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
   recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   ```
2. custom Adapter

   ```
     class CardDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

   private List<CustomCard> dataSet;

   public CardDataAdapter(List<CustomCard> list) {

       dataSet = list;
   }


   @Override
   public CardDataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
       // create a new view
       View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
               R.layout.row_custom_card, null);

       itemLayoutView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

       // create ViewHolder

       CardDataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new CardDataAdapter.ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);

       return viewHolder;
   }


   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(CardDataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

       CustomCard fp = dataSet.get(i);

       viewHolder.tv_title.setText(fp.getName());


       viewHolder.feed = fp;
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {

       return dataSet.size();
   }

   // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
   public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       public TextView tv_title;

       public NotificationModel feed;

       public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
           super(itemLayoutView);

           tv_title = (TextView) itemLayoutView  .findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
           itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                  //Write here

               }
           });



          }

       }
    }
   ```
3. note : CustomCard is model & row_custom_card layout xml where name Textview resde

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to the `CardArrayRecyclerViewAdapter` constructor must be of type `List<Card>`. I know it seems like `List<CustomCard>` should work here, but it will not.

It's impossible to say what the best way to solve this problem is without seeing more code, but you could do this:

```
List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
cards.addAll(customCards);
// now call constructor with `cards` instead of `customCards`
```

You can read more about why `List<CustomCard>` is not accepted for the `List<Card>` argument here [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)